# Binding list property to TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a class named MyClass which looks like this:

```
public class MyClass : BaseObject, IDisposable
{
    public int MyClassId { get; set; }

    public IList<MyClassTranslation> MyTranslations { get; set; }
}
```

And MyClassTranslation looks like this:

```
public class MyClassTranslation
{
    public string MyClassName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view and a view model. The View model looks like this:

```
class MyClassViewModel : ViewModelBase, IMyClassViewModel
{
    public MyClassViewModel()
    {
        myObjects = GetMyObjects();
    }

    public IList<MyClass> myObjects { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding myObjects}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">                            
                    <TextBlock FontSize="24pt" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding MyClassTranslation.MyClassName[0]}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The problem is that the myClassName property isn't shown. How do I bind it?

Comment: did you try `MyTranslations[0].MyClassName`? `MyTranslations` is a list, not `MyClassName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that the data context is set properly, so the proper binding would be

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">                            
    <TextBlock FontSize="24pt" 
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               TextAlignment="Center" 
               Text="{Binding MyTranslations[0].MyClassName}">
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

you can use indexer to bind such values